# Как сделать чтобы написаное приложение на Python с GUI интерфейсом работало в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

**Здравствуйте кодеры, Хочу реализовать свое приложение так чтобы, то при закрытии работало в фоновом режиме**

**— Типа вот так:**

[image: Пример фоновых приложений]

**Что можете посоветовать, какие фреймворки библеотеки, сложно ли это вообще реализовать?**

Comment: Вот тут пример с использованием pystray: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1162558/1365

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095030/%d0%9e%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-windows/1095044#1095044